# WPF with C# code that generates HTML that exports to Excel and include images

Tags: c#, html, wpf, excel

Hello so here is my problem.  I currently have a stand alone WPF application that has a web browser control. I have some code that is in C# that generates an HTML page that I use as the content for the Web Browser.  My issue is that I am trying to export this HTML page to excel and have the images included in it.  This is how I am currently exporting my HTML to an EXCEL file:

```
  string filePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".html";

  //Creates an HTML file from the web browser and save it to a temp location
  File.WriteAllText(filePath, GenerateHtml());

  //Creates a new instance of Microsoft office interop for using MS Excel
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
  //Create a new instance of a workbook
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add();
  //Don't Show MS Excel
  excelApp.Visible = false;
  //Open a file at location
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook2 = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath);
  //Convert that file to an XLSX document

  SaveFileDialog newSFD = new SaveFileDialog();
  newSFD.FileName = "Report in Excel Format";
  newSFD.DefaultExt = ".xls";
  newSFD.Filter = "XLS Documents (.xls)|*.xls";
  Nullable<bool> result = newSFD.ShowDialog();

  if (result == true)
  {
    string fileName = newSFD.FileName;
    excelWorkBook2.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    //Close excel
    excelApp.Quit();
  }
```

Everything exports okay and all the information is there but for some reason there are no images.  The table where the images should be are there and it has place holders where the images should go which is why I am so confused.  If there is anymore explanation required please let me know and I will provide it, otherwise thank you for the help/concern with this issue.

Comment: check your image src and make sure its pointing to a proper location...

Comment: I should note that the HTML Page that is generates has everything correct and displays the images just fine.

@Stan R.  Yes I am trying to implant the images into Excel

Comment: i'm sorry, i misread that..you're trying to implant the images into excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a lot of digging/trial and error, and research I found my solution, and as always it is right in front of you.  The issue was simply when I was saving the XML Document as an excel file as show in the question I was handling it in this manner:

```
excelWorkBook2.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlXMLSpreadsheet, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

When in actuality I should have been saving it like this:

```
excelWorkBook2.SaveAs(fileName, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveConflictResolution.xlUserResolution, true, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

The difference between the two is that instead of saving the XML document as a xlXMLSpreadsheet, I needed to save the file as an xlWorkBookNormal.  Once I made this change it allowed me to save my file as an excel document and included the images along with it. Simple solution to what I considered a more interesting problem.